# Windows forms invoke tooltip as method

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-5

How can I invoke tooltip for different TextBoxes? I tried to use this code

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowToolTip("test", textBox1);
        toolTip1.IsBalloon = false;
        toolTip1.Show("test", textBox1, 4000);
    }

    static void ShowToolTip(string text, TextBox element)
    {
        toolTip1.IsBalloon = false;
        toolTip1.Show(text, element, 4000);
    }

}
```

I don't understand why in button1_Click method I can access to the toolTip1, but in the custom method ShowToolTip I get [CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0120)) *"An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'"* error.
Also is this a good way to do a method overloading for each element type e.g. Label, Button etc?

Comment: Where do you declare `toolTip1`?

Comment: The `ShowToolTip()` method is marked `static`, so it cannot access instance fields or properties. You could either pass the ToolTip object as parameter, or just leave the method non static.

Comment: @fildor I don't know i just drag and drop tooltip element to the form.

Comment: _"Also is this a good way to do a method overloading for each element type e.g. Label, Button etc?"_ - no need. [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ToolTip_Show_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_) expects an `IWin32Window` and that's what I'd use as argument type.

Comment: _"I don't know i just drag and drop tooltip element to the form"_ - The designer will create non-static class fields. So, @bassfader's comment applies.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my code:

```
    void ShowToolTip(string text, IWin32Window element)
    {
         toolTip1.IsBalloon = false;            
         toolTip1.Show(text, element, 4000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your ToolTip object as parameter to your ShowToolTip static method, becouse you using static method in side non static Form class

```
static void ShowToolTip(string text, TextBox element, Control control)
    {
        var myToolTip = control as ToolTip;
        if (myToolTip == null)
        return;

        myToolTip.IsBalloon = false;
        myToolTip.Show(text, element, 4000);
    }
```